# how to hide this url using mysite.com

Tags: php, html, video, server

on my website there is something like

```
<source src = "https://x3.test-cdn.com/656cd437b72/teste.m3u8" type = "application / x-mpegURL">
```

and I would like it to look like this:

```
<source src = "https://example.com/jhfakdhakjsdkasdhadfdf" type = "application / x-mpegURL">
```

as if it were a proxy, I tried with fopen (), readfile (), but I can't think of anything to work

appreciate

Comment: You are basically eliminating any benefit from a CDN then, in favor of potentially serving the file more slowly, and burning your server's bandwidth in the process.

Comment: does your CDN allow you to map subdomains, so (eg) asset.example.com could replace the x3.test-cdb.com/665... path? or perhaps have a url rewrite rule on your server so requests to assets get redirected?